# Card Matching Game - PHP - On clicks?

Tags: php, onclick, logic

I have to make a entirely php, game (on a page using html and css obviously). While the basica logic behind it like matching cards and all that is easy enough I have one big issue. I need to let the user select the card by clicking the card. Not by clicking a button beneath it, or entering the card they want to pick or so on. They need to click on the card, it will flip, then they click on another, it will flip, and if they match the dissapear, if not, they flip over again.

But as far as I know, PHP doesn't have onclick events, and I can't use javascript for this. Does anyone have a general idea as to what to do for this? I was considering making them all buttons with the card images as the actual content of the button, but I don't know how I would handle the input from that and so on.

If anyone has any ideas, or suggestions as to how I can go about this I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I think you've already covered the sensible and sane bases. Either use Javascript, or they have to click a button to invoke a page load with PHP. "I was considering making them all buttons with the card images as the actual content of the button" that's like driving your cucumber to work because you don't have a car...

Comment: click image wrapped in herf- fuggly but it will work

Comment: It's not that I don't WANT to use javascript, it's that I can't. It's for a school assignment and we lose ALOT of marks for javascript.

Comment: `<a href="file.php?card=AH"><img src="AH.jpg"></a>` file.php knows what they just clicked- store it in a session return the page with the card flipped for then next selection

Comment: could I have them all as submit buttons, individually check them with isset, and then unset them afterwards?

Comment: seems no diffident than using regular urls